# How a constant is derived from equation in Kullback-Liebler divergence

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, constants

From Kullback-Liebler divergence of matrix factorization;
\begin{equation*} \mathrm{X}\approx\mathbf{WH} \tag{1} \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*} d_{\mathrm{KL}} (\mathbf{X}\ \vert\vert \mathbf{WH})=\sum_{f,t}\left(X_{f,t}\log\frac{X_{f,t}}{WH_{f,t}}-X_{f,t}+WH_{f,t}\right) \tag{2} \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*} \stackrel{\hbox{cst.}}{\hbox{=}} \sum_{f,t}-X_{f,t}\log\sum_{k}{WH_{f,t}} + \sum_{f,t}\sum_{k}{WH_{f,t}} \tag{3} \end{equation*}

How is constant in $(3)$ derived from $(2)$? Why does $X_{f,t}\log{X_{f,t}}-X_{f,t}$ disappear?

[Reference](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~njb/teaching/sstutorial/part2.pdf) (page 77)